# SVPullToRefresh - Refresh view does not show

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

Sorry if my question seems stupid but I've been trying everything to get it to work for several days now and nothing comes to my mind anymore.

I'm trying to use SVPullToRefresh on a UIScrollView which is, in my storyboard, fixed to the main view of my View Controller (space constraints to superview 0,0,0,0).

Code is pretty straightforward :

```
__weak ALExploreViewController *weakSelf = self;
[self.globalScrollView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
[weakSelf refreshData];
}];
[self.globalScrollView triggerPullToRefresh];
```

The thing is, when I launch the app, the pull to refresh appears as I triggered it in code. Then I make it disappear when my data are updated (`self.globalScrollView.showsPullToRefresh = NO;`). And then when I scroll up to refresh, the "pull to refresh" view won't show. If I deactivate bouncing, the view won't event scroll upper than y=0, and if I activate it, it bounces but no sign of the P2R view.

Any ideas ? Please ?

Comment: I think your problem is using it in a scroll view; according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html): **Note: Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a different context can result in undefined behavior.**

Comment: I don't know, the readme explicitly tells that any UIScrollView or subclass can use the category (which is, BTW, a UIScrollView category containing a custom UIView, not using UIRefreshControl at all). The thing is, the content of my app doesn't quite comply with a UITableView design. I really need to be able to apply this to my scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `self.globalScrollView.showsPullToRefresh = NO;`, this is used to disable the refreshView.
When your data is updated, you can call
`- (void)stopAnimating;`
Try it!